# Can an Azure Data Factory that is part of subscription A interact with objects in subscription B?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have 2 Azure subscriptions, can and ADF environment in one subscription interact with databases in the other subscription?  Both subscriptions are under the same tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. ADFs can interact with database even if they are in another subscription .
They can even interact with database in different tenant

Comment: As long as the databases are in the same tenant as the ADF, they can access the databases in any subscription via managed identity or service principal .in case if the database is in another tenant,then one can acess only via SQL auth